# Is it possible to have currying and variadic function at the same time?

Tags: functional-programming, currying

I am thinking about making currying and variadic functions both available in a dynamically-typed functional programming language, but I wonder if it is possible or not.

Here are some pseudocode:

```
sum = if @args.empty then 0 else @args.head + sum @args.tail
```

which is supposedly to sum all its arguments. Then, if `sum` itself is treated a number, then the result is `0`. for example,

```
sum + 1
```

is equal to 1, assuming that `+` can only work on numbers. However, even `sum == 0` is true, `sum` will still maintain its value and functional property no matter how many arguments are given (hence "partially applied" and "variadic" at the same time), for example, if I declare

```
g = sum 1 2 3
```

then `g` is equal to `6`, however, we can still further apply `g`. For example, `g 4 5 == 15` is true. In this case, we cannot replace the object `g` by a literal `6`, because although they yield the same value when treated as an integer, they contain different codes inside.

If this design is used in a real programming language, will it cause any confusion or ambiguity?

Comment: Strictly speaking, using currying as a fundament of a language means that **all** functions are unary - not only are there no variadic functions, there aren't even any binary ones! However, programs in that language will still *look as if* they took multiple arguments, and that goes for variadic functions just as much as for normal ones.

Comment: Then my question is simplified to "can an object be a function and a non-function value at the same time?" In the above example, `sum` is `0` without an argument and recursively calls itself with an argument.

Comment: isn't that the job of `reduce`?

Comment: Take a look at the functions you're using on `args`: `empty`, `head`, and `tail`.  Those are all list functions, suggesting that maybe the easier and more straightforward thing to do would be to use a list where the variadic stuff would be.  (So, `sum [1, 2, 3]` instead of `sum 1 2 3`)

Answer (score 6):

How can varargs be implemented? We need some mechanism to signal the end of the argument list. This can either be

- a special terminator value, or
- the length of the vararg list passed as an extra parameter.

Both of these mechanisms can be used in the context of currying to implement varargs, but proper typing becomes a major issue. Let's assume that we are dealing with a function `sum: ...int -> int`, except that this function uses currying (so we actually have a type more like `sum: int -> ... -> int -> int`, except that we don't know the number of arguments).

Case: terminator value: Let `end` be the special terminator, and `T` be the type of `sum`. We now know that applied to `end` the function returns: `sum: end -> int`, and that applied to an int we get another sum-like function: `sum: int -> T`. Therefore `T` is the union of these types: `T = (end -> int) | (int -> T)`. By substituting `T`, we get various possible types such as `end -> int`, `int -> end -> int`, `int -> int -> end -> int`, etc. However, most type systems do not accommodate such types.

Case: explicit length: The first argument to a vararg function is the number of varargs. So `sum 0 : int`, `sum 1 : int -> int`, `sum 3 : int -> int -> int -> int` etc. This is supported in some type systems and is an example of *dependent typing*. Actually, the number of arguments would be a type parameter and not a regular parameter – it would not make sense for the arity of the function to depend on a runtime value, `s = ((sum (floor (rand 3))) 1) 2` is obviously ill-typed: this evaluates to either `s = ((sum 0) 1) 2 = (0 1) 2`, `s = ((sum 1) 1) 2 = 1 2`, or `s = ((sum 2) 1) 2 = 3`.

In practice, none of these techniques should be used since they are error-prone, and don't have a (meaningful) type in common type systems. Instead, just pass a list of values as one paramter: `sum: [int] -> int`.

Yes, it is possible for an object to appear as both a function and a value, e.g. in a type system with coercions. Let `sum` be a `SumObj`, which has two coercions:

- `coerce: SumObj -> int -> SumObj` allows `sum` to be used as a function, and
- `coerce: SumObj -> int` allows us to extract the result.

Technically, this is a variation of the terminator value case above, with `T = SumObj`, and `coerce` being a un-wrapper for the type. In many object-oriented languages, this is trivially implementable with operator overloading, e.g. C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sum {
  int value;
public:
  explicit sum() : sum(0) {}
  explicit sum(int x) : value(x) {}
  sum operator()(int x) const { return sum(value + x); }  // function call overload
  operator int() const { return value; } // integer cast overload
};

int main() {
  int zero = sum();
  cout << "zero sum as int: " << zero << '\n';
  int someSum = sum(1)(2)(4);
  cout << "some sum as int: " << someSum << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer! The drawback with packing varargs up in a list is that you lose the partial application of currying. I was toying with a Python version of your terminator approach, using a keyword argument `..., force=False)` to force the application of the initial function.

Comment: You could make your own higher order function that partially applies a function that takes a list, like `curryList : ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> [a] -> b, curryList f xs ys = f (xs ++ ys)`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [this implementation of printf in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html), along with [this description of how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828072/how-does-haskell-printf-work).  There's a link on the latter page to Oleg Kiselyov's paper on doing this kind of thing, which is also worth reading.  In fact, if you're designing a functional language, [Oleg's web site](http://okmij.org/ftp/) should probably be compulsory reading.

In my opinion, these approaches are a bit of a hack, but they show that it is possible.  If your language features full dependent typing, however, it's much simpler.  A variadic function to sum its integer arguments could then look something like this:

```
type SumType = (t : union{Int,Null}) -> {SumType, if t is Int|
                                         Int,     if t is Null}
sum :: SumType
sum (v : Int) = v + sum
sum (v : Null) = 0
```

An abstraction for defining the recursive type without needing to give it an explicit name might make writing such functions easier.

Edit: of course, I just read the question again and you said a *dynamically* typed language, at which point obviously the type mechanics aren't really relevant, and therefore @amon's answer probably contains everything you need.  Oh well, I'll leave this here in case anyone comes across this while wondering about how to it in a static language...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for currying of variadic functions in Python3 that uses the "terminator" approach of @amon, by taking advantage of Python's optional arguments:

```py
def curry_vargs(g):
    actual_args = []
    def f(a, force=False):
        nonlocal actual_args
        actual_args.append(a)
        if force:
            res = g(*actual_args)
            actual_args = []
            return res
        else:
            return f
    return f

def g(*args): return sum(args)
f = curry_vargs(g)
f(1)(2)(3)(4,True) # => 10
```

The returned function `f` collects arguments passed to it in successive calls in an array that is bound in the outer scope. Only when the `force` argument is true the original function is called with all arguments collected so far.

Caveats of this implementation are that you always have to pass a first argument to `f` so you cannot create a "thunk", a function where all arguments are bound and can only be called with the empty argument list (but I think this is in line with the typical implementation of curry).

Another caveat is that once you pass a wrong argument (e.g. of the wrong type) you have to re-curry the original function. There is no other way to reset the internal array, this is only done after a successful execution of the curried function.

I don't know if your simplified question, "can an object be a function and a non-function value at the same time?", can be implemented in Python, as a reference to a function without parentheses evaluates to the internal function object. I don't know if this can be bent to return an arbitrary value.

It would probably be easy in Lisp, as Lisp symbols can have a value and a function value at the same time; the function value is simply selected when the symbol appears in function position (as the first element in a list).